# Save/ load large array of shorts to binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I am trying to write and subsequently read a very large array of short data to a file.  I am getting a successful write, but on the read, I get a bad bit on rdstate at a seemingly random point during the read long before the end of file.  Here is a minimal run-able snippet of my current code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    short * inData = new short[512 * 512 * 361];
    //fill with dummy data
    for (int z = 0; z < 361; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 512; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++)
            {
                inData[x + y * x + z * y * x] = x + y + z;
            }
        }
    }

    //write file
    {
        std::ofstream outfile("data.bin", std::ios::out, std::ios::binary);
        if (outfile.is_open())
        {
            //header
            char buffer[10] = "vol_v1.00";
            outfile.write(buffer, 10);
            //dimensions
            int dims[] = { 512,512,361 };
            outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dims), std::streamsize(3 * sizeof(int)));
            //spacing
            double spacing[] = { 0.412,0.412,1 };
            outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(spacing), std::streamsize(3 * sizeof(double)));
            //data
            outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&inData[0]), sizeof(inData[0]) * dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2]);
            std::cout << "write finished with rdstate:  " << outfile.rdstate() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    short * outData = new short[512 * 512 * 361];
    //read file
    {
        std::ifstream infile("data.bin", std::ios::in, std::ios::binary);
        if (infile.is_open())
        {
            // get length of file:
            infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
            long length = infile.tellg();
            infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);
            std::cout << "file length: " << length << std::endl;

            //header
            char buffer[10];
            infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), 10);
            std::string header(buffer);

            //dimensions
            int* dims = new int[3];
            infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dims), std::streamsize(3 * sizeof(int)));

            //spacing
            double* spacing = new double[3];
            infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(spacing), std::streamsize(3 * sizeof(double)));

            infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&outData[0]), std::streamsize(sizeof(outData[0]) * dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2]));
            std::cout << "ending pointer pos: " << infile.tellg() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "read finished with rdstate:  " << infile.rdstate() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    free(outData);
    free(inData);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I have other attempts where I read in chunks, but for brevity just did the single chunk here as the issue seems the same.  But with chunks, the data is read for a few hundred thousand values and then fails with bad bit.

Comment: sry I was using calloc to initialize to zero, I can switch to malloc if it makes it easier to run

Comment: Unless someone can cut and paste your sample code, exactly as is, and successfully compile it, your shown code fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. P.S. Is the created file's byte size matches what's expected. P.P.S. Modern C++ has no need for ugly, crufty callocs or mallocs, like this. All dynamic memory allocation that's needed here is more safely done by using `std::vector`, and, to put, you don't have to remember to `free` the memory. `std::vector` will do it for you.

Comment: I have this snippet running in an empty main, should I copy the whole c++ file with main and header?

Comment: file size matches ya, it comes up as 184,895 KB in windows explorer

Comment: No. Don't copy "the whole C++ file". Only the minimum required to reproduce the problem. This is the "minimal" part of a [mcve]. If you demonstrate that you took effort to minimalize the amount of work others need to do in order to reproduce your problem, rather than just dumping a huge pile of code for others to decipher, you will find it more likely for others to help you.

Comment: `prog.cpp:20:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream<char>')`

Comment: I am sorry, I honestly am at a loss for why you are getting errors... I am running that code in vs 2015... its a cmake project... but that shouldn't matter as its compiling through vs 15 compiler

Comment: Yeah, an obvious problem with the parameters to ifstreams and ofstreams' constructors. gcc on Linux refuses to accept this error, and detects it; and once the obvious problem is fixed, the program runs without errors. I suspect that Microsoft's compiler fails to detect this problem. Which only serves to show that someone who's serious about learning C++ will use Linux, where C++ is a first class citizen.

Comment: I will look more closely into proper usage of those constructors thank you!

Comment: Yes, you want `std::ios::in | std::ios::binary`. Ditto for the other constructor too. Pay close attention. Microsoft's buggy compiler treats the 3rd parameter as the file permission bit parameter, and completely fraks everything up.

Comment: omfg thank you so much... I have been chasing ghosts on this one for 2 days... thought the error was in my memory handling.

Comment: Should I reword the question to help better describe the issue or delete it? (my code works swimmingly now)

Comment: No, just leave the question as is, and post a self-answer, explaining what the problem is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two calls to fstream are incorrectly made.  As written, it still compiles in VS2015 but does not properly set the two flags (write and binary), resulting in the stream error seen above.  Below are the correct calls to write and read a binary file:

```
std::ofstream outfile("data.bin", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);

std::ifstream infile("data.bin", std::ofstream::in | std::ofstream::binary);
```